# TTFB Delayed 22 seconds (Angular7 + IIS Server)

Tags: angularjs, web, angular-ui-router, iis-7.5, server-side-rendering

We are implementing angular SSR for our website SEO purpose. All the integration then node &inode installation everything done and site is working fine in UAT and QA environments. when we move the patches to production environment we are facing TTFB delay with 21.3 seconds. We are not sure why these environement based issue occured. Becuase production environement also installed same softwares and configurations all same. But these delays we are not able to identify the root cause.

ANgular7
IIS
Windows Server

Comment: You need to know where the delay happened. So check IIS log or enable [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). In log files to see when IIS got the request and when IIS sent response. If the delay happened in IIS, failed request tracing log will record which module caused it.

Comment: THanks for the reply Brush. As per your input I haveenabled the log and found the issue. But not detailed format. If possible can you help me to understand. In the log I got below information. But I'm not sure about solution. Module Name: iisnode
Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
TYPE: MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_SUCCESS_STATUS